# Can I pass keyword args to do-blocks in julia?

Tags: julia

Below is an example:

```
def(f::Function) = f

f1 = def() do x
    x
end

f2 = def() do x, y
    x, y
end

f3 = def() do x, y; z # this syntax is accepted
    x, y, z
end

f1(1)
f2(1, 2)
f3(1, 2, z=3) # ERROR: LoadError: function #13 does not accept keyword arguments
```

The example below is not my actual use case, but it illustrates the question. How should I handle kwargs in a do-block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. If you look at /src/julia-parser.scm file you can find that parsing of a do block is defined in `parse-do` [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/julia-parser.scm#L1545). And you can see that `do`-block is rewritten to an anonymous function that can only accept positional arguments in `doargs` variable separated by commas.

In [this](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/julia-parser.scm#L1549) line you can see that `;` explicitly terminates parsing of arguments of `do`-block. This means that:

```
julia> z = "hello"
"hello"

julia> f3 = def() do x, y; println(z) # this syntax is accepted
           x, y, z
       end
#24 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f3(100, 1000)
hello
(100, 1000, "hello")
```

will work as the code past `;` is treated as a part of `do`-block body.

You could try to put `(` and `)` around the arguments like this:

```
julia> f3 = def() do (x, y; z)
           x, y, z
       end
ERROR: syntax: invalid assignment location "; z"

julia> f3 = def() do (y; z)
           y, z
       end
ERROR: syntax: "begin
    y
    # REPL[52], line 1
    z
end" is not a valid function argument name
```

This will go through parser, but then julia-syntax.scm will throw an error. This probably could be improved as:

```
f3 = def(function(x, y; z)
    x, y, z
end)
```

works correctly (you can consider opening an issue for this on https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues).

Until this is fixed the only thing you can do is to use anonymous function definition approach I have given above (although it is not very clean).

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a bug/issue or a feature. Anyway, your reply clears up some things, thanks!

Comment: See https://discourse.julialang.org/t/allowing-for-keyword-arguments-in-do-block/19244/1, actually it would lead to an inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, you just need to pass the `kwargs` before the `do`:

```
julia> f(g, xs; kwargs...) = begin
           println(kwargs...)
           map(g,xs)
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(1:5; thisworks=true) do x x^2 end
:thisworks => true
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  4
  9
 16
 25
```